# Devo criar uma tabela por categoria, ou uma única tabela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Quero montar um site de classificados e tenho uma dúvida: como eu posso fazer a criação das categorias no BD? Crio uma tabela de anúncios pra cada categoria? Ou crio uma tabela `Categorias` com elas dentro? Qual a melhor forma?

Comment: Essa pergunta está um pouco ampla, não?

Comment: Ampla? Não vejo nada de ampla..só queria saber como posso fazer (a melhor forma é fazendo X ou fazendo Y) isso é amplo?

Comment: Faça uma tabela para categorias, com chave estrangeira.

Comment: Acho que modelagem e normalização não é um assunto amplo, não é atoa que existem tags para isso.

Comment: **NÃO crie uma tabela para cada categoria**.

Comment: Se a única coisa que varia de uma categoria pra outra é o nome e o identificador único (ID), não crie mais tabelas.

Answer (score 4):

Se categoria é um conceito bem fechado, o ideal é **não** criar uma tabela para cada categoria.

Um bom exercício de sanidade: imagine que você já tem mil notícias no site, e agora toda notícia ou categoria precisa ter uma coluna a mais. Você prefere fazer alterações - e ainda correr o risco de errar - em apenas uma tabela ou em vinte?

Existem duas formas de se lidar com categorias, no seu caso:

- **Uma tabela de categorias, e a tabela de notícias tem chave estrangeira pra ela.** Isso traz duas vantagens: ao mudar o nome da categoria você atualiza todas as notícias dela automaticamente, e para adicionar uma categoria nova basta adicionar um registro em uma tabela.
- **Categoria como uma coluna de tipo textual na tabela de notícias.** Isso pode ser visto por muita gente como desnormalização. Isso simplifica o `schema` do banco e, dependendo de como for feito, pode tornar as buscas mais rápida. Mas para atualizar uma categoria, você precisa atualizar todos os registros de notícia daquela categoria.

Se a categoria for ter mais informações além do nome, sugiro preferir a primeira forma.